# View which Chrome extension uses a specific IndexedDB

Tags: google-chrome, storage, cache

In AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/IndexedDB, I have one particular folder that takes up nearly 2GB. The folder is titled chrome-extension-.indexeddb.blob, so I have reason to believe that one of my installed extensions is using up quite a big amount of space. I'd like to find out which one it is, and if it happens to be one that has no business taking up that much space, I can safely delete the folder.

So how do I see which folder "owns" the particular IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a manual answer myself. By going into chrome://extensions, and clicking on "Details" for each, the URL bar shows the ID of the given extension, which matches the ID used in the IndexedDB folder.